# Heroku Logs get forbidden error message on iterm

Tags: heroku

```
heroku logs -t
 ▸    Forbidden
```

That's the output I'm getting, I'm in the right subdirectory, unsure if there's permissions I need to change on Heroku?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Heroku was just down for a brief period of time.